# Altorouter path differences on localhost vs remote server

Tags: php, .htaccess, path, localhost, altorouter

I am wondering how to remove "/" from link paths in .htaccess (I assume) when navigating a site on localhost (localhost/mysite) that was is on the root of a remote server ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)).
This routing is done with Altorouter and in order to get any functionality I added setBaePath("/myProject") which works.
My problem is that any links in the site (e.g. "/home") have a slash that results in the browser going to "localhost/home" instead of "localhost/mysite/home".
Do I need to make changes to the .htaccess file to parse out "/" from all the links within the site?

.htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]


<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php)$">
  FileETag None
 <ifModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalidate"
 </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

index.php
(The 2 lines I added to index.php have a "*" in front of them.)

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
* require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/altorouter/altorouter/Altorouter.php';



$router = new AltoRouter();
* $router->setBasePath('/mysite');

// MAIN PAGES
$router->map('GET', '/', function() {
    require __DIR__ . '/../views/hello.php';
});
$router->map('GET', '/home', function() {
    require __DIR__ . '/../views/home.php';
.
.
.

$match = $router->match();

// call closure or throw 404 status
if( is_array($match) && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {
    call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] ); 
} else {
    // no route was matched
   header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
}
```

Comment: I understand that the base path to your application differs between your localhost and some other http server you want to install your application on. What I don't understand is why you can't simply use _relative_ paths throughout your application and combine those with _relative_ rewriting rules. That way those rules will match regardless of the path the application is installed at.

Comment: The files were originally on a http server and have relative paths.  (/home). There was no basepath used with the Altorouter in index.php (I believe because the site was in the root (https://livesite.com). To get Altorouter to work on localhost/myTestSite I had to add (router->setBasePath = "/myTestSite"). I had to change relative path links on pages from ("/home") to ("home") otherwise instead of "localhost/MyTestSite/home" I get "localhost/home". I somehow need to strip the / of links. Not sure how to do this in .htaccess

Comment: `/home` actually is an _absolute_ path. Because of the leading slash ("/"). That anchors the path to the root, which means it is absolute. A relative path woult be `home`, so without leading slash. If you code references using _relative_ paths, then you do not have the issue you currently work on.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately changing the paths from absolute to relative would require changing them back after I finish making the edits to the site as it will be uploaded back to the remote server. I guess (hope) I could put all the files in htdocs (using XAMPP) so it would be localhost/home

Comment: I fail to understand that issue. The whole point of using _relative_ path as references inside a web application is to _not_ having to change those paths because of a distribution. Those references work regardless of the base path. They only refer _inside_ some location.

Comment: Thanks! That does make sense. Not sure why the person who coded the application chose to use absolute paths.

Comment: The only thing you need to take care is when to refer to pages within the app from different locations (different "virtual folders"). Because using relative paths means you might need different paths depending on from where you refer to a page. That is a question of how internal references are structured. Some applications are not suitable for relative references I am afraid.

Comment: I ended up changing the path in httpd.conf in XAMPP to make the project directory the root (localhost). At least it works although not a solution for working on other projects. Thanks a lot for all your help arkascha!